# AngularJS array with Objects

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, arrays

im working with the angularjs framework.
Here is my Code first:

```
var app = angular.module('app',['ngRoute','ngAnimate']);

app.controller('maincontroller',function($scope,$http) {
    $scope.planes = [];

    $scope.createPlanes = function() {
        $http.post('api/create_plane.php',{
        }).success(function(data,status,headers,config) {
            console.log(data);
            for(var result in data)
                {
                    $scope.planes = [
                        {"planeLMID": data[result]['planeLMID']}
                    ];
                }
            console.log($scope.planes);
        });
    };
    $scope.createPlanes();
});
```

And this is the return of the console.log(data);

```
Object {1: Object, 2: Object, 3: Object, 4: Object, 5: Object, 6: Object, 7: Object, 8: Object, 9: Object, 14: Object, 15: Object, 16: Object, 17: Object, 18: Object, 20: Object, 21: Object, 23: Object, 24: Object, 25: Object, 26: Object, 27: Object, 29: Object, 31: Object, 32: Object, 33: Object, 34: Object, 35: Object, 36: Object, 37: Object, 38: Object}
```

And a sample of how a object in it look like

```
planeAFID:    "89-3412"
planeCPISPI:    ""
planeLMID:     "8215"
```

so i want to do a $scope.planes array with a for loop.
But after the first object it doenst fill anymore. How can i push the other objects into the array?

Thanks

Comment: You could do `$scope.planes.push( {"planeLMID": data[result]['planeLMID']})`

Comment: Oh god, sorry for that small fail from me.
Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using push function of the array you can achive this.

```
$scope.planes=[];
for(var result in data)
{
  $scope.planes.push({"planeLMID": data[result]['planeLMID']});

}
console.log($scope.planes);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the **push** method, *$scope.planes.push('insert what you want to push here')*

Answer (score 0):

You should use the array's `.push()` method

```
var app = angular.module('app',['ngRoute','ngAnimate']);

app.controller('maincontroller',function($scope,$http) {
    $scope.planes = [];

    $scope.createPlanes = function() {
        $http.post('api/create_plane.php',{
        }).success(function(data,status,headers,config) {
            console.log(data);
            $scope.planes = [];
            for(var result in data)
            {
                $scope.planes.push({"planeLMID": data[result]['planeLMID']})
            }
            console.log($scope.planes);
        });
    };
    $scope.createPlanes();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this.

```
$scope.planes = [];

$scope.createPlanes = function() {
    $http.post('api/create_plane.php',{
    }).success(function(data,status,headers,config) {
        console.log(data);
        for(var result in data)
            {
                $scope.planes.push({
                    "planeLMID": data[result]['planeLMID']
                });
            }
        console.log($scope.planes);
    });
};
$scope.createPlanes();
```